# Proving that a function $g:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}, (x_1, x_2)\mapsto g(x)=\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^4}$ is not continuous at $x=0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I would like to prove that the following function $g:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is not continuous at $x=0$
$$
g(x)=\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^4}
$$
if $x\ne 0$ and equal to $0$ if $x=0$.

It's pretty clear that $g$ is continuous to every straight line throught $0$ at $0$. I don't see how can I proceed to prove this discontinuity of $g$ at $0$.

Comment: Have you checked if you get _the same_ limit, approaching $x=0$ along different lines?

Comment: You haven't even tried $x_1=x_2$, have u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove it isn't continuous it suffices to find a path such that the sublimit isn't $g(0,0)$.

> "It's pretty clear that $g$ is continuous to every straight line throught $0$ at $0$. I don't see how can I proceed to prove this discontinuity of $g$ at $0$."

Let $k\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and consider the paths $t\mapsto \left(kt,t\right)$, (these are lines).

One gets $$\lim \limits_{\mathop{(x,y)\to (0,0)}_{\large{ky=x}}}\left(g(x,y)\right)=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\left(\dfrac{kt^2}{k^2t^2+t^4}\right)=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\left(\dfrac{k}{k^2+t^2}\right)=\frac 1 k.$$

So you made a mistake somewhere, your first idea should have worked.

Comment: Yep I made a stupid calculation mistake, thanks.

Comment: @Gato No problem. There's a word for it, if you're interested, [miscalculation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/miscalculate?q=miscalculation).

Answer (score 1):

Use parabolas! Make $x_1 = t^2$, $x_2 = t$ and make $t \to 0$. We get: $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t^2t}{(t^2)^2+t^4} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t^3}{2t^4} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{2t},$$which clearly does not exists.